# How noticeable is Fetch?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, animal-companions

While I was looking through the rules for *Pathfinder's* [Fetch](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWpq2IqLfJAhXFeT4KHeOQCCUQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.d20pfsrd.com%2Fskills%2Fhandle-animal&usg=AFQjCNHMSlaNtcvmIS4O4Dl_lxl_Hg9nLg)
 trick, I failed to see how it works in certain situations. As such, I would like to know how obvious an animal taking an object from a person or place is. For instance, could a trained companion steal a key from a guard if their back was turned?

Comment: Why would you just not use the animal's Slight of Hand against the guard's Perception?

Comment: Depending on the type of the animal companion, this could be an odd sight.

Comment: I have a horse.

Comment: @Areadbhair You just won't have any luck having the horse do it with mage hand. You're going to have to have the horse sneakily trot in and grab it with his mouth. That's gotta be a huge DC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible!

You would want to get the animal to roll Stealth or Slight of Hand or a similar skill against the guard's perception, however you may also want to discuss with your GM about bonuses to skill checks.

For example: A rat might have a stealth bonus when fetching small items such as keys, whereas a large dog might have a negative bonus to stealth due to its size.

Happy adventuring!